# How to use switch statements if you have four inputs

Tags: c++

A class has four exams in one term. Input each exam score and assign the corresponding grades.

90 and above is A
80 to 89 is B
70 to 79 is C
60 to 69 is D
below 60 is F
below 0 is invalid

I can only code using 1 input not 4

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

int a;

cout<<"Input Examination Score: ";
cin>>a;

switch (a / 10){
case 0: 
case 1: 
case 2: 
case 3:
case 4:
case 5: cout <<"Equivalent is F"<<endl;
break;
case 6: cout <<"Equivalent is D"<<endl;
break;
case 7: cout <<"Equivalent is C"<<endl;
break;
case 8: cout <<"Equivalent is B"<<endl;
break;
case 9:
case 10: cout <<"Equivalent is A"<<endl;
break;
default: cout <<"Invalid Score"<<endl;
break;
}
```

---

Comment: You may need a loop?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but a switch statement is not the appropriate tool here. Use an `if` `else if` ladder: `if (a >= 90) /* grade is A */; else if (a >= 80) /* grade is B */;`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in different ways. You can either use a for-loop or a while/do-while loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) // runs 4 times
{
    //Do your thing
}
```

Or you can create a variable with the value of 4, use a while/do-while loop 
and decrease it by 1 each semester until it is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop to read the input multiple times, then calculate the average when printing the result:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int number_grades = 4;
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<number_grades; ++i) {
        int a;
        cout<<"Input Examination Score: ";
        cin>>a;
        sum +=a;
    }

    switch ((sum/number_grades) / 10){
    case 0: 
    case 1: 
    case 2: 
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5: cout <<"Equivalent is F"<<endl;
        break;
    case 6: cout <<"Equivalent is D"<<endl;
        break;
    case 7: cout <<"Equivalent is C"<<endl;
        break;
    case 8: cout <<"Equivalent is B"<<endl;
        break;
    case 9:
    case 10: cout <<"Equivalent is A"<<endl;
        break;
    default: cout <<"Invalid Score"<<endl;
        break;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There were a few that I've changed but still thank you.